# Fragment not filling up entire screen/parent layout Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout, android-framelayout

I have a FrameLayout in my app that is being replaced by a Fragment that contains a RecyclerView, but when it does that, the RecyclerView doesn't fill up the whole FrameLayout, there's a border around it.

[image]

Parent Layout, this is what is called from MainActivity, it contains the FrameLayout that is going to be replaced:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.jggdevelopment.wannacook.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout_for_fragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/navigation_toolbar"
    tools:context="com.jggdevelopment.wannacook.MainActivity"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment it's being replaced with, a RecyclerView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fridge_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/fab_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/floating_button"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
        fab:fab_labelsPosition="left"
        fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_plus_white_24dp"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/colorAccent"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/colorAccentPressed">

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="addNewItem"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/white"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/whitePressed"
            fab:fab_title="Add new item"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_restaurant_black_24dp"
            />

    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Code in MainActivity used to replace Fragment:

```
else if (id == R.id.nav_fridge) {
        FridgeFragment fridgeFragment = new FridgeFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(
                R.id.relative_layout_for_fragment,
                fridgeFragment,
                fridgeFragment.getTag()
        ).commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please remove padding on FrameLayout.

```
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Answer (score 1):

> Make this changes in your Frame Layout
>
> remove:

```
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

> Or use this Frame Layout in your layout (i have made the changes )

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_layout_for_fragment"
            tools:showIn="@layout/navigation_toolbar"
            tools:context="com.jggdevelopment.wannacook.MainActivity"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        </FrameLayout>
```